# Saving the image within the rectangle from camera preview android camera2?

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I have a viewpoint rectangle on my camera preview frame. Now, my idea is to only capture the image from the viewpoint and save it in my internal storage. I used the             `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRect);`
but for some reason when I specify the coordinates of the rectangle and the image is saved, it looks like the image is zoomed out when it saves, as a result, some part of the image within the viewpoint is cut off. I tried adjusting the x,y positions but it doesn't seem to work. What could be the problem? I am using camera2 API. This is my code

```
 private void captureStillPicture() {
        try {
            final Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (null == activity || null == mCameraDevice) {
                return;
            }
            // This is the CaptureRequest.Builder that we use to take a picture.
            final CaptureRequest.Builder captureBuilder =
                    mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE);
            captureBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());

            // Use the same AE and AF modes as the preview.
            CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

            CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraDevice.getId());







            Size[] jpegSizes = null;
            if (characteristics != null) {
                jpegSizes = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP).getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG);



            }
            int width = 640;
            int height = 480;
            if (jpegSizes != null && 0 < jpegSizes.length) {
                width = jpegSizes[2].getWidth();
                height = jpegSizes[2].getHeight();
            }





            int x = width/5;
            int y = height/6;
            int topX = x + (250 / 4) ;
            int topY = y + (250 / 5);
           Rect cropRect = new Rect(topX,topY,x,y);

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SCALER_CROP_REGION, cropRect);

            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
            setAutoFlash(captureBuilder);

            // Orientation
            int rotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
            captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.JPEG_ORIENTATION, getOrientation(rotation));

            CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback CaptureCallback
                    = new CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCaptureCompleted(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession session,
                                               @NonNull CaptureRequest request,
                                               @NonNull TotalCaptureResult result) {
                    showToast("Saved: " + mFile);
                    Log.d(TAG, mFile.toString());
                    unlockFocus();
                }
            };

            mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
            mCaptureSession.abortCaptures();
            mCaptureSession.capture(captureBuilder.build(), CaptureCallback, null);
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image: Saved image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?